# Vector-based HTML Canvas Drawings

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, vector

I'm creating nice icons using HTML Canvas feature. But I've just noticed that they're all pixel-based, I mean raster graphics, not vectors. I'm leaning more into using HTML Canvas than  using SVG. The way Canvas works is very similar to SVG anyway; namely, they both serve lines and curves defined by mathematical equations. So I wonder if there's a way to render those images as vectors or at least to get them pre-scaled (e.g 2x bigger) if realtime scaling is not possible at all.

Comment: Ouch! You want to convert thousands of raster images to vector?  Bring a big check to a graphic artist that knows Illustrator.

Comment: Actually no. Canvas feature lets you generate images by specifying coordinates, angles, colors etc. I just wonder if there's a way to get them scaled on certain times without any quality loss if not render them as vectors. I can use Illustrator by the way.

Comment: Well if you have access to Illustrator you might also have access to Photoshop.  How about creating an Action that resizes an image (maybe your 2X) and then use a Batch command to process every file in a folder.

Comment: That's not the question. The question is the presentation of the images on browsers. No external image file will be used, they're all codes.

Comment: You can easily scale 2X in canvas but with quality loss.  You can scale 2X in Photoshop with minimal quality loss. You can convert the image in Illustrator to vector and then scale without quality loss. But no, there's no way to render raster images as vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use svgs?

Sorry, cant comment. Not enough credit.

Comment: I'm dealing with thousands of images so I don't want to be a CPU-raper.